# SQL QUERY: Joining of two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem in getting the correct data...

I have two tables, *tblbuilding and tbldata.*

Here's my *tblbuilding*:

[image]

Here's my *tbldata*:

[image]

my query:

My fldWeek here is "Week 3":

```
SELECT tblbuilding.fldBldgName
      ,tblbuilding.fldNetname
      ,MAX(tbldata.fldDuration) AS fldDuration
      ,tbldata.fldWeek
      ,tbldata.fldYear
FROM tblbuilding AS tblbuilding_1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbldata ON tblbuilding_1.fldBldgName = tbldata.fldBldgName 
    CROSS JOIN tblbuilding
WHERE (tblbuilding.fldNetname = 'LRT - 2') 
    AND (tbldata.fldWeek = 'Week 3' OR tbldata.fldWeek IS NULL)
    AND (tbldata.fldYear = '2013' OR tbldata.fldYear IS NULL)
GROUP BY tbldata.fldWeek
        ,tblbuilding.fldBldgName
        ,tblbuilding.fldNetname
        ,tbldata.fldYear
ORDER BY tblbuilding.fldBldgName
```

The result of the query above is:

[image]

Which is correct....

but when I changed the fldWeek to "Week 2"

the result is:

[image]

The correct result should be...."assuming that I have only two NOT NULL in WEEK 2"

[image]

Thanks....

Comment: A comment on your table design: why do you have an `id` field, your primary key I assume, and then join on `fldBldgName`? Either use the surrogate key and have a `fldBldgid` in `tbldata` or do away with the surrogate keys and make the name your primary key and have a composite key in the `data` table.

Comment: I smell pinoy here. Anyway, you are using `SQL Server` right? not `MySQL`.

Comment: @今 草 顿 웃...HAHA SORRY... YEs I'm using SQL SERVER

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to get the cartesian product.

Try this using `LEFT JOIN` only.

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.fldBldgName,
        b.fldDuration,
        b.fldWeek,
        b.fldYear
FROM    tblBuilding a
        LEFT JOIN tblData b
            ON  a.fldBldgName = b.fldBldgName
                AND b.fldWeek = 'Week 3'
                AND b.fldYear = '2013'
WHERE   a.fldNetname = 'LRT - 2'
```

Comment: You have a syntax error on `AND tbldata.fldYear = '2013'`. Did you mean to write `AND b.fldYear = '2013'`?

Comment: @今草顿웃...what do you mean of this "FROM tblBuilding a LEFT JOIN tblData b" the "a" and "b"

Comment: @PrincessToledo they are called `ALIAS`. instead of writing long tablenames, i preferred to use them. You are using SQL Server right, kabayan?

Comment: @PrincessToledo - It's short for `tblBuilding AS a` just as you have used `MAX(tbldata.fldDuration) AS fldDuration`. In SQL Server the `AS` keyword is optional.

Comment: @今草顿웃...UHH..its kinda okay now...But the other NetName besides "LRT - 2" are also displayed...the "mass and mobile"....

Comment: @PrincessToledo - No, in that case the table name alias is _used_ to select fields from the table; `a` & `b` are just shorthand to save typing the full table name. Both table names and Field names can be replaced with aliases.

Comment: my bad. `a.fldNetname = 'LRT - 2' ` should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @今草顿웃....hey! thank you so much~! i thought I will not fix my problem anymore.. :D you save my life

Comment: @PrincessToledo you're welcome! *Ingat sa Araneta Center - Cubao, madami magnanakaw dyan!*